# When using the DelayQueue of Java, should I implement equals() and hashCode() as well?

Tags: java, static-analysis, findbugs

I'm currently dealing with a class that's using a `DelayQueue`. I've noticed that since the objects in the `DelayQueue` implement the `Delayed` interface, the said objects need to implement a `compareTo()` method as well, which has already been done.

**Does this implicitly mean that I also should consider implementing an `equals()` method and a `hashCode()` method as well?**

The reason why I'm asking is because I stumbled upon [**this advice**](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#EQ_COMPARETO_USE_OBJECT_EQUALS) when searching through the project via [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), and I'm trying to figure out whether it's needed or not for this particular case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a good practice, yes, since `equals`, `hashCode` and `compareTo` has close meanings. They can be seen as different aspects of the same thing. If you object is used someplace else without implementing them together, you may meet unpredictable behavior.

For example, you've passed your object to a 3rd party library which use binary search algorithm, it uses `compareTo`. Several months later, the new version of the library change to hashed based data structure to improve performance, which relay on `equals` and `hashCode`. From their point of view, it's not breaking change。

As in this case, no, since `DelayQueue` doesn't use the them.

Comment: Great answer, +1 for sure. One thing I reflected upon while reading through the Findbugs explanation of this was that this could be a problem for the PriorityQueue, which uses compareTo in Java 5, but in java 6 it used equals instead. Just a heads-up. :)