# Does java.util.concurrent.Delayed really force me to violate equals/compareTo consistency?

Tags: java, concurrency, equals, compareto

Trying to use Java's `DelayQueue`, I have to implement the `Delayed` interface which requires a `compareTo()` ["method that provides an ordering consistent with its getDelay method."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Delayed.html#getDelay%28java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). The intention is of course that the `DelayQueue` can easily sort the queued objects such that the next one running out of its delay can be returned to any taker.

Now I have the need to also remove objects from the queue ahead of time. I need to call `delayQueue.remove(queuedObject)`. This of course only works if the queued objects have an `equals()` method that reflects their payload and not the completely unrelated remaining delay time.

As a result, `compareTo()` is based on the remaining delay time while `equals()` is based on the payload of the queued objects, so they are not consistent, as is "strongly recommended" in the [javadoc of `Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Question: am I missing something or is this indeed a bit of a quirk in the design of `DelayQueue`?

Comment: Well, it's "strongly recommended (though not required)", so I would not say you have to violate something. There're some classes in JRE which have `compareTo` inconsistent with `equals`, including `ScheduledFutureTask` which implements `Delayed`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446736/when-using-the-delayqueue-of-java-should-i-implement-equals-and-hashcode-as

Answer (score 0):

The available wiggle room may be in the ambiguity of the requirement that ths ordering is *consistent* with its `getDelay` method. What does *consistent* mean? Can it mean using the `getDelay` values as the primary ordering, and allowing use of other attributes as a secondary ordering, to break ties for objects that have equivalent `getDelay`values? If so, you would be OK if the `equals` method requires equality of the `getDelay` values and all the attributes that the `compareTo` method uses for tie breaking, but does not require equality of any other attributes. This really means that the `Delayed` class must have value semantics.

Answer (score 0):

That two objects are insufficiently different as to justify ranking one above the other does not imply that the objects are identical.  As a simple example, one may wish to sort strings using a case-insensitive string comparison, but only regard two strings as equivalent when their uppercase/lowercase usage matches.  By such standards, "FRED" and "Fred" would not be unequal, but would be unranked relative to each other.  I would suggest that it is more important to have `equals` indicate semantic equivalence than to have it be "consistent" with `compareTo`.